# Remove # from a Variable

Tags: variables

I am using WordPress WooCommerce plugin as a store management. When I echo with `<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>` I get #6453 as a result but I need only numbers so how do I strip out # from the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the first character of the string:

```
echo substr( $order->get_order_number() , 1 );
```